# Speed of operations on misaligned data

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

To my knowledge, a CPU performs best with a datum that is aligned on the boundary equal to the size of that datum. For example, if every `int` datum is 4 bytes in size, then the address of every `int` must be a multiple of 4 to make the CPU happy; same with 2-byte `short` data and 8-byte `double` data. For this reason, `new` operator and `malloc` function always return an address that is a multiple of 8 and, therefore, is a multiple of 4 and 2.

In my program, some time-critical algorithms that are meant to process large byte arrays allow striding through the computation by converting each contiguous 4 bytes into an `unsigned int` and, in this way, do the arithmetic much faster. However, the address of the byte array is **not** guaranteed to be a multiple of 4 because only a part of a byte array may need to be processed.

As far as I know, Intel CPUs operate on misaligned data properly but at the expense of speed. If operating on misaligned data is slower enough, the algorithms in my program would need to be redesigned. In this connection I've got two questions, the first of which is supported with the following code:

```
// the address of array0 is a multiple of 4:
unsigned char* array0 = new unsigned char[4];
array0[0] = 0x00;
array0[1] = 0x11;
array0[2] = 0x22;
array0[3] = 0x33;
// the address of array1 is a multiple of 4 too:
unsigned char* array1 = new unsigned char[5];
array1[0] = 0x00;
array1[1] = 0x00;
array1[2] = 0x11;
array1[3] = 0x22;
array1[4] = 0x33;
// OP1: the address of the 1st operand is a multiple of 4,
// which is optimal for an unsigned int:
unsigned int anUInt0 = *((unsigned int*)array0) + 1234;
// OP2: the address of the 1st operand is not a multiple of 4:
unsigned int anUInt1 = *((unsigned int*)(array1 + 1)) + 1234;
```

So the questions are:

1. How much slower is OP2 compared to OP1 on x86, x86-64, and Itanium processors (if neglect the cost of type casting and address increment)?
2. When writing cross-platform portable code, about what kinds of processors should I be concerned regarding misaligned data access? (I already know about RISC ones)

Comment: Couldn't you answer your own question 1 with a simple loop?

Comment: @Blindy - The OP may not have access to processors with those architectures.

Comment: I don't know, he listed pretty much every processor out there so unless he's using an abacus or something he should have at least one of them.

Comment: @Blindy I'd like to know the speed difference at the lowest level, like CPU registers and the related operations.

Comment: @Naveen: You might have to go lower than that, actual chip circuits.

Comment: In truly portable code even the computation of `anUInt1` may fail, resulting in *undefined behavior*. On some sane, current platforms, the memory access to the unaligned data will throw an exception and probably terminate your process (SPARC at least).

Comment: This is not something that can be answered here adequately. You'll need to test, profile, etc.

Comment: I don't know anything about those specific processors, but I know the delay can vary from trivial to 10x or worse.  In some architectures the code takes an unaligned operand interrupt and the fetch/store is simulated.  And generally store will be significantly worse than fetch since a memory/cache word boundary may be crossed.  Finally, it's highly workload dependent -- whether there are spare CPU cycles or memory/cache cycles.  A modest testcase would give you a clue, but could be misleading.

Comment: I don't think there is one answer to this. It depends on the processor implementation

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: Hmm... I thought that main issue (at least with fetching data) is that processor have to get two words instead of one and then translate those words into one. Actually you can simulate same behavior and it might be faster if you need to walk through array of such numbers (you'll reuse those snippets of neighbor words for next iteration).

Comment: The processor must get two words, possibly with two cache faults (and many architectures deal poorly with double faults), then mask/rotate the words as needed (potentially requiring several ALU cycles).  An extra internal register is needed to hold the second value while "splicing" them, and often that register is not easily accessed, requiring multiple cycles to load or store.  Lots of complicated logic, and many designers are not inclined to spend gates to do it super-efficiently if it's rare enough.

Comment: ARM can be even worse than SPARC. No crash, just wrong data. And with Windows 8 coming to ARM, that may be an even bigger concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are far too many processors on the market to be able to give a generic answer. The only thing that can be stated with certainty is that some processors cannot do an unaligned access at all; this may or may not matter to you if your program is intended to run in a homogeneous environment, e.g. Windows.

In a modern high-speed processor the speed of unaligned accesses may be more impacted by its cache alignment than its address alignment. On today's x86 processors the cache line size is 64 bytes.

There's a Wikipedia article that might provide some general guidance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment